settings for cheapest azure serverless sql db?
I am trying to configure a serverless sql db in azure, which I will use for development.
So far I've created a db instance, but have not connected to it, and have no code calling it.
The only thing I have done is use my local SSMS to connect for a few minutes for me to create a test table (id int(pk), test name varchar(50)), and insert two records.
Here are the specs:
{
    "sku": {
        "name": "GP_S_Gen5",
        "tier": "GeneralPurpose",
        "family": "Gen5",
        "capacity": 1
    },
    "kind": "v12.0,user,vcore,serverless",
    "properties": {
        "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "maxSizeBytes": 1073741824,
        "status": "Paused",
        "databaseId": "___obfuscated___",
        "creationDate": "2024-04-29T00:55:41.923Z",
        "currentServiceObjectiveName": "GP_S_Gen5_1",
        "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "GP_S_Gen5_1",
        "defaultSecondaryLocation": "westus",
        "catalogCollation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "zoneRedundant": false,
        "maxLogSizeBytes": 193273528320,
        "earliestRestoreDate": "2024-04-29T01:05:10Z",
        "readScale": "Disabled",
        "currentSku": {
            "name": "GP_S_Gen5",
            "tier": "GeneralPurpose",
            "family": "Gen5",
            "capacity": 1
        },
        "autoPauseDelay": 60,
        "currentBackupStorageRedundancy": "Local",
        "requestedBackupStorageRedundancy": "Local",
        "minCapacity": 0.5,
        "pausedDate": "2024-05-02T07:55:47.203Z",
        "maintenanceConfigurationId": "___obfuscated___",
        "isLedgerOn": false,
        "isInfraEncryptionEnabled": false,
        "availabilityZone": "NoPreference"
    },
    "location": "eastus",
    "tags": {},
    "id": "___obfuscated___",
    "name": "___obfuscated___",
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
}



The cost summary estimates shown by Azure:
General Purpose (GP_S_Gen5_1), Cost per GB (in USD)0.12
Max storage selected (in GB) x 1.3
ESTIMATED STORAGE COST / MONTH = 0.15 USD
COMPUTE COST / VCORE SECOND 1 = 0.000145 USD

The problem... I am being charged approximately $1 per day (each day!), which is a lot more than I was expecting, especially for a db that is not being used.
Please let me know what I should modify in the settings to make it cheaper (or free) to operate as a development db.

Azure now offers some free resources, and SQL Database is one of them, although there are some prerequisites to meet

An Azure account

If you're evaluating Azure, consider the Azure free account, with many services available free for 12 months.
While the previous offer required an Azure Free subscription, this new offer is available regardless of your Azure subscription type.


An Azure subscription that doesn't already have a SQL Database with the free offer applied.

There's a limit of one free amount database per subscription.



And also there's montly limits

The monthly free limits include 100,000 vCore seconds of serverless database compute and a maximum size of 32 GB of data.

You have two options you can set in the Behavior when free limit reached setting:

Once the monthly limits on vCore activity or storage are met, the database can be auto-paused until the beginning of the next calendar month.

This is the Auto-pause the database until next month option.


Keep the database online, with vCore usage and storage amount over the free limits charged to your subscription's billing method, at the standard General Purpose tier serverless rates.

This is the Continue using database for additional charges option.
Regardless, the free amount renews at the start of the next calendar month.



This offer is available for one database per Azure subscription. To get started, look for the Apply offer banner on the provisioning page for Azure SQL Database


The free Azure SQL Database offer is currently in preview.

To create your database, follow these steps:

Go to the Azure portal provisioning page for Azure SQL Database.
On the Basics tab, look for the banner that says "Want to try Azure SQL Database for free?", select the Apply offer button.
Provide the information requested, if have any question, please check the remaining steps here

